# How can I copy and paste part of a split URL using Selenium and Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, chromedriver

I have split URL, and I need to copy and paste a part of that split URL.  It gives me an error when I use `send_keys` method:

```
url_parts[4].send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

What can I do to copy and paste this split URL? Please, I need help.

Answer (score 2):

Alexey R. is right. Error message is quite obvious.

You need to locate the INPUT `element`, convert parts you want to paste to a single string, and `element.send_keys()` that value to located `element`. No need to copy-paste anything, keep it all in Python variables.

Comment: Upvote for keeping value in variables. This obvious thing didn't come to my mind. This won't only work if we need to test the pasting feature which supports some non-classic (custom) inputs that are handled by javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in Python however it looks like you're trying to invoke `send_keys` from a String object. Key events can only be sent to browser objects.

So having an array of strings you need to use some Python library that allows copying to clipboard. They might differ since all OSs might implement clipboard in their own ways and some might have no clipboard at all. You can refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python) for details on **OS Windows case**.

Then having a string moved to a clipboard you can try to invoke <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on the UI object where you'd like to paste the value to.